# Accessing plan id during Stripe response

Tags: php

Here the json sent by Stripe to get invoices status:

```
Stripe\Collection JSON: {
  ...
  "data" => [
    [0] => Stripe\Invoice JSON: {
      ...
      "lines": {
        "data": [
          {
            ...
            "subscription": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "plan": {
              "interval": "month",
              "name": "X-Large - 12 mois",
              "created": 1435711579,
              "amount": 52800,
              "currency": "cad",
              "id": "X-LARGE_12M",
              "object": "plan",
              "livemode": false,
              "interval_count": 12,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "statement_descriptor": null
            },
            ...
          }
        ],
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The json response can be found here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_customer_invoices

I would like to access to the `plan id` (i.e.: `X-LARGE_12M`).

So I tried:

```
$invoice->lines->data->plan->id
```

But it doesn't work.

It works for others fields.

Any reason why ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"data": [
          {
```

The `data` element is an *array* of objects. So you'd need something like

```
foreach($invoice->lines->data as $data) {
  echo $data->plan->id, "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: `$invoice->lines->data[0]->plan->id` makes the thing.